# Run Object notebook in Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to execute this code on databricks in scala. Everything is in an object, then I have a case class and def main and other def functions.

Trying to work with "package cells" but I got **Warning: classes defined within packages cannot be redefined without a cluster restart.
Compilation successful.**

removing the object didn't work either

```
package x.y.z

import java.util.Date
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

object Meter {
  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")

  case class Forc (cust: String, Num: String, date: String, results: Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val inputFile = "sv" //  
    val outputFile = "ssv" // 
    val fileSystem = getFileSystem(inputFile)
    val inputData = readLines(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true).toSeq
    val filtinp = inputData.filter(x => x.nonEmpty)
      .map(x => Results(x(6), x(5), x(0), x(8).toDouble))

  def getTimestamp(date: String): Long = dateFormat.parse(date).getTime

  def getDate(timeStampInMills: Long): String = {
    val time = new Date(timeStampInMills)
    dateFormat.format(time)
  }

  def getFileSystem(path: String): FileSystem = {
    val hconf = new Configuration() 
    new Path(path).getFileSystem(hconf)
  }

      override def next(): String = {
        val result = line
        line = inputData.readLine()
        if (line == null) {
          inputData.close()
        }
        result
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have `package` declaration at beginning - remove it, and just move all declarations from the object into the cells

Comment: I used the package declaration after reading the suggestion in databricks info page, was not there before, the code works in Intelij(without the package line) with no issues at all, you suggestion refers to keep the same structure? i.e everything inside the object and then move all declaration in the same cells or can run separately ?

Comment: After remove the package declaration at beginning  When I run on databricks; it says 'defined object Meter'